# Fade image of button from one image to another via a float value

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

In my use case, I have a slider that moves from 0.0 to 1.0. When moving that slider I want a button's image to fade from one image to another smoothly. The button will only transition between two images. As one fades in, the other fades out and vice-versa.

There are answers on SO on how to change the image of a button over a fixed duration but I can't find something based on a changing float.

So is there a way to change the image of a button over a duration from one image to another based on a float that changes from 0.0 to 1.0?

EDIT:
For example, imagine a button that transitions smoothly from an image of a red star to a green star as you move the slider back and forth. (I know you could accomplish this other ways but I want to use two images)

Comment: Did you try with `button.imageView` property ?

Comment: Did you try with by adding target for valueChanged ?

Comment: @MiteshDobareeya No, I'm not sure how I would go about using that

Comment: @Micro Please check my answer.

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Can you provide an answer of what you're thinking?

Comment: @Micro I am sure I have your answer below or at least how I understand your question. Care to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot.  It is doing what you want I think. The trick is to set the layer speed to 0 and just update the timeOffset.

```
import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        lazy var slider : UISlider = {
            let sld = UISlider(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: self.view.frame.height - 60, width: self.view.frame.width - 60, height: 20))
            sld.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderChanged), for: .valueChanged)
            sld.value = 0
            sld.maximumValue = 1
            sld.minimumValue = 0
            sld.tintColor = UIColor.blue
            return sld
        }()


        lazy var button : UIButton = {
            let bt = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 60, width: 150, height: 150))
            bt.center.x = self.view.center.x
            bt.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPress), for: .touchUpInside)
            bt.setImage(UIImage(named: "cat1"), for: .normal)

            return bt
        }()


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.view.addSubview(button)
            self.view.addSubview(slider)
        }

        override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewDidAppear(animated)
            addAnimation()
        }

        func addAnimation(){
            let anim = CATransition()
            anim.type = kCATransitionFade
            anim.duration = 1.0

            button.layer.add(anim, forKey: nil)
            button.layer.speed = 0
            button.setImage(UIImage(named: "cat2"), for: .normal)
        }


        @objc func sliderChanged(){
            print("value \(slider.value)")
            button.layer.timeOffset = CFTimeInterval(slider.value)
        }

        @objc func buttonPress(){
            print("pressed")
        }
    }
```

Here is the result:
[image: slidegif]

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 4

```
//This is slider
@IBOutlet weak var mSlider: UISlider!

//Add Target for valueChanged in ViewDidLoad
self.mSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.onLuminosityChange), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)

//called when value change
@objc func onLuminosityChange(){
    let value = self.mSlider.value
    print(value)
    if value > 0.5 {
        btnImage.imageView?.alpha =  CGFloat(value)
        UIView.transition(with: self.btnImage.imageView!,
                          duration:0.3,
                          options: .showHideTransitionViews,
                          animations: { self.btnImage.setImage(newImage, for: .normal) },
                          completion: nil)

    }else{
        btnImage.imageView?.alpha =  1 - CGFloat(value)
        UIView.transition(with: self.btnImage.imageView!,
                          duration:0.3,
                          options: .showHideTransitionViews,
                          animations: { self.btnImage.setImage(oldImage, for: .normal) },
                          completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Or Inset an Action directly via Storyboard/XIB

[image]

Comment: @Micro but you can set alpha based on slider value to button imageview. See my edited answer. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is another workaround, since i tired with single button but couldn't achieve the result, so what i did is i took two buttons overlaying each other, with same size, constraints and each with separate image.

```
var lastSlideValue : Float = 0.0
@IBOutlet weak var slideImage: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var btnImageOverlay: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btnSecondOverlayImage: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    btnImageOverlay.imageView?.alpha = 1.0
    btnSecondOverlayImage.imageView?.alpha = 0.0
}
@IBAction func sliderValueChanged(_ sender: Any) {//UIControlEventTouchUpInside connected method
    let sliderr = sender as? UISlider
    let value = sliderr?.value

    if lastSlideValue < (sliderr?.value ?? 0.0) {
        btnSecondOverlayImage.imageView?.alpha =  CGFloat(value!)
        btnImageOverlay.imageView?.alpha =  1 - CGFloat(value!)
    } else if lastSlideValue == sliderr?.value {
        print("equal")
    } else {
        btnImageOverlay.imageView?.alpha =  CGFloat(value!)
        btnSecondOverlayImage.imageView?.alpha =  1 - CGFloat(value!)
    }

}
@IBAction func userTouchedSlider(_ sender: Any) { //UIControlEventValueChanged connected method
    let sliderr = sender as? UISlider
    lastSlideValue = (sliderr?.value)!
}
```

[image]

> You could use cross fade animations with single button, but binding it with slider is difficult task. Let me know if you need any assistance with the same.

Comment: I want the slider to only fade between two images. As one fades in the other fades out as you move the slider.

Comment: @Micro,please check the update answer, hope this workaround helps you.